# After updating to android 2.2.3, I am getting a number of cannot resolve method errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = this.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.user), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = pref.getString(getString(R.string.user), null);
    if (username.length() == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

After I updating my android studio to 2.2.3, methods such as getString(R.string.user), startActivity(Intent), new Intent(this, Login.class), and getSharedPreferences() all give cannot resolve method errors. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you give it time to rebuild your projects?  Depending on what you upgraded from you probably have to wait for gradle to sync, and rebuild.

If you're still having issues, try cleaning and rebuilding explicitly.